# How to remove curly brackets from the PowerShell output

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-powershell, aws-certificate-manager

This is regarding AWS Certificate manager:

```
Get-ACMCertificatelist | Get-ACMCertificateDetail | Select -ExpandProperty renewalsummary | Where-object {$_.renewalStatus -ne "Success"}
```

Following is the output and I want to remove those curly brackets:

```
DomainValidationOptions                   RenewalStatus       
-----------------------                   -------------       
{Certificate1}                         PENDING_AUTO_RENEWAL
{certificate2}                         PENDING_AUTO_RENEWAL
```

Answer (score 2):

The object in question is actually giving you an array for the `DomainValidationOptions` part, which can contain more than one value.

```
| Select @{n="DomainValidationOptions";e={($_.DomainValidationOptions -join ",")}},RenewalStatus
```

putting this on the end of your query will replace the `DomainValidationOptions` with a comma-separated string instead of an array, but keep the name, in cases where there's only one option this technically just converts it to a string.

Comment: Following is the Output and that is not correct:
DomainValidationOptions                          RenewalStatus       
-----------------------                          -------------       
Amazon.CertificateManager.Model.DomainValidation PENDING_AUTO_RENEWAL
Amazon.CertificateManager.Model.DomainValidation PENDING_AUTO_RENEWAL

Comment: @user8172425 You'll need to do `$_.DomainValidationOptions.Something` then - find what `.Something` is which contains the actual string, you can get that by running `Select -Expand DomainValidationOptions`

Answer (score 1):

Those are automatically added when converting a collection to a string in the formatting cmdlets. You can format the objects yourself to get rid of them.

Comment: I am new to powerShell. Is there any sample code format them?

Comment: I have no clue how your objects look like (regarding properties and nesting structure), so I can't give you any example code.

Comment: Name                    MemberType Definition                                                                                                          
----                    ---------- ----------                                                                                                          
DomainValidationOptions Property   System.Collections.Generic.List[Amazon.CertificateManager.Model.DomainValidation] DomainValidationOptions {get;set;}

Comment: RenewalStatus           Property   Amazon.CertificateManager.RenewalStatus RenewalStatus {get;set;}

Answer (score 1):

You can specify [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for each of the properties of DomainValidationOptions that you want to drill down into.

### Step 1) Discover Properties

Pipe DomainValidationOptions to `Get-Member -MemberType Property` to see what properties you're going to be working with:

```
Get-ACMCertificateList |
Get-ACMCertificateDetail |
Select -ExpandProperty RenewalSummary |
Select -ExpandProperty DomainValidationOptions |
Get-Member -MemberType Property


   TypeName: Amazon.CertificateManager.Model.DomainValidation

Name             MemberType Definition
----             ---------- ----------
DomainName       Property   string DomainName {get;set;}
ValidationDomain Property   string ValidationDomain {get;set;}
ValidationEmails Property   System.Collections.Generic.List[string] ValidationEmails {get;set;}
ValidationStatus Property   Amazon.CertificateManager.DomainStatus ValidationStatus {get;set;}
```

### Step 2) Make Request

For the sake of example, lets say that we only want to retrieve DomainName and ValidationDomain. We would add two calculated properties for each of these properties, and then just do a regular select for RenewalStatus on the RenewalSummary object:

```
Get-ACMCertificateList | 
Get-ACMCertificateDetail | 
Select -ExpandProperty RenewalSummary | 
Where-object {$_.RenewalStatus -ne "Success"} |
Select @{N='DomainName';E={$_.DomainValidationOptions.DomainName}}, `
       @{N='ValidationDomain';E={$_.DomainValidationOptions.ValidationDomain}}, `
       RenewalStatus
```

#### Example Output:

```
DomainName                 ValidationDomain           RenewalStatus
----------                 ----------------           -------------
*.subdomain.mydomain.com   mydomain.com               PENDING_AUTO_RENEWAL
mything.mydomain.com       mydomain.com               PENDING_AUTO_RENEWAL
```

You can perform a similar operation for ValidationEmails, I didn't include it in this example because that would have made too many properties to format cleanly on Stack Overflow. If you wanted to unroll the collection and convert it into a string, its calculated property would look something like this:

```
@{N='ValidationEmails';E={$_.DomainValidationOptions.ValidationEmails -join ','}}
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS PowerShell Documentation - Get-ACMCertificateDetail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-ACMCertificateDetail.html)
- [AWS SDK For .NET Documentation - Amazon.CertificateManager.Model.CertificateDetail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=CertificateManager/TCertificateManagerCertificateDetail.html&tocid=Amazon_CertificateManager_Model_CertificateDetail) 
   - There is an especially helpful note in here about RenewalSummary: "This field exists only when the certificate type is AMAZON_ISSUED."
- Additional Note For Readers: I had to update to latest AWS PowerShell to be able to see RenewalSummary.  If you can't see this property but expect that you should be able to, try updating your local AWS PowerShell version.